# How to set Android Gradle plugin in Android Studion 2021.3.1?

Tags: java, android, plugins

I recently upgraded to Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 and when I try to Build an old project I get an error about wrong plugin. In particular:

```
Build file 'C:\dev\AndroidProjects\Apps\Gmap3\app\build.gradle' line: 2
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

*Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
   Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre*
```

I checked all the settings in my project but I can't figure out where the plugin is specified.
**Can anybody help me understand?** I am not a noob but Dolphin has throw me for a loop. I think I have set JAVA_HOME and JAVAPATH correctly. I also did a "Sync Project with Gradle Files". I also restarted Android Studio. I have also installed the latest Java version.

Comment: just download the latest jdk and replace it with the one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre*`

Comment: There's a setting in Android Studio for the JDK it uses, it can be different from the one JAVA_HOME points to. Can you check that?